# How to set One to many relation in android room DB in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have two tables. First table is as below

```
    @Entity
    data class GramPanchayatSurveyEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    var gpCode: Int,
    var distCode: Int,
    var locationTypeCode: Int,
    var location: String,
    var latitude: String,
    var longitude: String,
    var googleLocation: String,
    var distanceBtwHeadQrToGp: String,
    var recommendedHeightOfTower: String,
    var BBNL_Exist: String,
    var anyCongestion: String,
    var nearByGpCode: Int,
    var surveyBy: String,
    var surveyAt: String,
    val status :String
)
```

And the second table as

```
@Entity
data class AddedPhotoEntity (
    @PrimaryKey
    var photoUniqueId:Int,
    var iPhotoTypeCode: Int,
    var photoTypeName: String,
    var sPhotoURL: String,
    var gpCode: Int,
    var photoStatus : String,
    var rotationAngle :Float
)
```

I have a relation class that fetches data from both tables as

```
class GpSurveyWithImageRelation {
     @Embedded
     var gpSurveyEntity: GramPanchayatSurveyEntity? = null

     @Relation(parentColumn = "gpCode", entityColumn = "gpCode")
     var sPhotoArray: List<AddedPhotoEntity>? = null
 }
```

When I am getting data from this relation and convert the data into JSON Array using gson it gives me the output like that

[This is the actual output of when I convert the list (getting from the relation) into a JSON array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAiDl.png)

[This is the required output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts38g.png)

Please anyone help me in creating the relation class between two tables so that I can got the required output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you have the var/field gpSurveyEntity Embedded as a **GramPanchayatSurveyEntity object**, instead you want `GpSurveyWithImageRelation` to be:-

```
data class GpSurveyWithImageRelation(
    var gpCode: Int,
    var distCode: Int,
    var locationTypeCode: Int,
    var location: String,
    var latitude: String,
    var longitude: String,
    var googleLocation: String,
    var distanceBtwHeadQrToGp: String,
    var recommendedHeightOfTower: String,
    var BBNL_Exist: String,
    var anyCongestion: String,
    var nearByGpCode: Int,
    var surveyBy: String,
    var surveyAt: String,
    var status :String,
    @Relation(entity = AddedPhotoEntity::class, parentColumn = "gpCode", entityColumn = "gpCode")
    var sPhotoArray: List<AddedPhotoEntity> = emptyList()
)
```